# Field of mesh lines

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm stumped to do the following project for a few days now and I would be grateful for any help :
Let's consider two series of points (blues and reds in the picture below).

[image]

I would like to connect all the possibilities between the blue points and the red points (and therefore not the red ones between them and the blue ones between them). For example, for the first red point, this would give the figure

[image]

But the idea of my project is to do it for all the points

I tried with the idea below
[image]

but I understood that Mesh line doesn't accept field....since then, I'm looking for the solution to my problem

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility is to make a line with a count of vertices that is the product of the point cloud sizes multiplied by two, and make this line goes alternatively from a point cloud to the other one.

As illustrated here (four points for 'cloud one' and three points for 'cloud two'):

[image]

Making that, one segment on two will overlap, so we'll merge after the calculation.

[image]

The top node line create the mesh line.

Then above, depending on the index parity, we pick on a point cloud or the other one using `sample index`node.

As result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot for your help ;)

Answer (score 2):

This version:

[image]

- Instances [sets of `Blue-Count` duplicates of a  Curve Line] on to each Red instance, stashing the `Duplicate Index`
- After realizing, moves the far `End Point` of each line to the position of the Blue instance with an `Index` corresponding to its own saved `Duplicate Index`

.. and decorates:

[image]

[image]